# Using text={binding var} property to validate value enter in a textbox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Sorry for my English,

I have a windows application using MVVM architecture. I have a View with differents controls. One of them is a textbox. I need to validate de user-entered value and set a specific value in the attribute and in a view if the user-entered value is incorrect. I must use the binding property of the textbox. It is not allowed me to use event control...for example PreviewTextInput.

For example, this is my control:

```
 <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I need In the case that the user enters digit the textbox does not allow this. I need In the case that the user enters negative number set value 1 in the attribute Name and show in the textbox this value. Also, I need if the user enters a value greater of 50 set in the attribute Name 50 and show in the view.

How I can do this?

thanks!

////////////////////////

thank you very much, Raul
the problem is that I cant displaying error messages (company policy...) I need to replace the erroneous value with a valid value. For example:

`public string Name`
    {

```
{get { return _name; }

set
{
_name = value;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
       // throw new ApplicationException("Customer name is mandatory."); 

    }
}
}
```

// Instead of throwing an exception, set in the textbox the numeric value            //50...like

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbCasesNumber.Text))
            {
                txtName.text= "50";
            }
```

How I can do this in WPF?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the validation in your view model's property. I suggest to read [Validation in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation), that is an excellent manual, and shows how validation works in WPF.

**UPDATE**

I found very useful things, first of all:

- [WPF Validation and MVVM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e464e8f-a7a0-4655-8647-7bf154b1e136/wpf-validation-and-mvvm): Excellent article that gives a pretty complete picture for validation with WPF.
- [ValidationRule with ValidationStep=“UpdatedValue” is called with BindingExpression instead of updated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342715/validationrule-with-validationstep-updatedvalue-is-called-with-bindingexpressi): This SO question has an aswer that shows a way for making what you want to do: set a value back, or custom value if validation fails.

Greetings ;) and Hope this helps...

Comment: I modified my question. How I can send a value to the view (in this case the textbox) if the user enters a wrong value. Watch the second part of my question please.